# Push hidden div from top on click

Tags: html

I would like to know is it possible to make a hidden div to be pushed down after clicking on a link?

So I have;

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="hidden-top"></div>
   <div class="navbar"></div>
</div>
```

This is a link where you can see it live: https://jivesoftware.com/. Just click on a language flag.

Comment: You mean to animate its height?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Inspect the code and see what's doing. `.hidden-top` must have `height: 0` and `transition: height...`, then you add a class that change its height.

Comment: Okay. Can I add content inside hidden-top even when it has height: 0px?

Comment: Yes, you can totally add content. CSS modifies the appearance of your elements independently of the content.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that 
for example

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div class'hidden-top'>I am hidden div</div>";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to show hidden div</button>
   <div class="navbar"></div>
</div>


<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is you can't hide it again with this code

Answer (score 0):

You may use class("hidden" in example bellow) to (VISUALLY) hide somthing. And toggle that class programmatically.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toggle)

function toggle() {
  document.getElementById("thatDiv").classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

```css
.forStyling {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
}

.hidden {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id='thatDiv' class="forStyling hidden">I am hidden div</div>
<button>Click me to show hidden div</button>
<p>
  Content that shifts down.
```